# Any way to change the color of a radio button?

Tags: android, radio-button, android-layout

I'm working on an android form with a radio group containing a set of radio buttons. From what I can tell there is no way to set the color a radio button highlights when you select it. It seems to always default to some bright green color. Is this something that is editable or no?

Thanks

Comment: I think it's a litle bit late to give you an ansewr, but you can check my ansewr to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35610511/1663453

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can create your own drawable for what you want it to look like when checked and use android:button to set it to the resource.

[Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516084/android-color-selector-with-radio-buttons/34519463#34519463)

Answer (score 1):

Use **AppCompatRadioButton** instead of RadioButton.

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb"
        app:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

To change the color programatically do this:

```
ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]{
                        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled} //enabled
                },
                new int[] {getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary) }
        );

AppCompatRadioButton radioButton = (AppCompatRadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb);
radioButton.setSupportButtonTintList(colorStateList);
```

Answer (score 0):

On api level 21+ you can change the buttonTint

```
<RadioButton
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/myId"
android:checked="true"
android:buttonTint="@color/accent"/>
```

Comment: And in API less than 21 or using compatibility: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35610511/1663453