# How do I get androids defualt control images

Tags: android, radio-button

I want to change the color used to indicate a selected radio button.  I've found an [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715950/any-way-to-change-the-color-of-a-radio-button) of how to do so.  The only thing I'm missing is a source of images to use.  To maintain a consistent appearance I want to take the existing images that are used by default and just recolor them.  I've seen a guide explaining to get the images in the past, but when I try searching I'm unable to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the images as part of the SDK:

> x:\path\to\SDK\platforms\android-17\data\res\drawable-mdpi

The images from the radio button beginns with `btn_radio`.

As [cafelatte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276183/cafelatte) notes you need to provide the 4 differnt [densities](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range). There are four types:

- **ldpi**: Resources for low-density (ldpi) screens (~120dpi)
- **mdpi**: Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline density.)
- **hdpi**: Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~240dpi).
- **xhdpi**: Resources for extra high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi).

Answer (score 2):

Either create your own resources, or pull what you need from the SDK.

In `${your-sdk-dir}\platforms\android-${apilevel}\android.jar`

Simply take the resources you need from under the **res\drawable*** subdirectories.  Don't forget to provide [l/m/h/x]dpi resources if required.