# How to change border color of radio button in android?

Tags: android

How to change border color of radio button in android?

I want to change circle color of android radio button.

Thanks in advance. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have try different soluation and concern if any property is there other that drawable image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2716089/1838457

Comment: android:buttonTint="@color/your_color"

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/52802572/4797289

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The easiest way to customize(change color) your views.

Goto : http://android-holo-colors.com/

- Select the color you want for Radio Button
- Download Output Resources (Download.Zip)
- Extract zip contents
- Copy files from extracted zip to your project drawables, styles and values
- Change the parent of your app theme to the one you downloaded
- And you have got what you wanted

Answer (score 24):

Yes, this is the property you are looking for: buttonTint, but only works on api level 21 or above

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radio"
    android:checked="true"
    android:buttonTint="@color/your_color"/>
```

in your values/colors.xml put your color in this case a reddish one:

```
<color name="your_color">#e75748</color>
```

Result:

[image: Colored Android Radio Button]

Comment: As far as I know, this only works on api level 21 or higher. This means that it will take no effect on lower version of android.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to tell, thanks, I've updated the post to include it

Answer (score 3):

Try using AppCompatRadioButton

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rb"
    app:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent" //This to set your default button color
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

For more detail check this answer : [Android: Change the color of RadioButtons and checkboxes programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472737/android-change-the-color-of-radiobuttons-and-checkboxes-programmatically/38565260#38565260)