# Change the circle color of radio button

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

I want to change the color of the circle of [RadioButton](https://zgrepcode.com/android/9.0.0/base.core/android/widget/radiobutton.java) in [one of my projects](https://imobilenumbertracker.com), but I could not understand which property to set. The background color is black, so it gets invisible. I want to set the color of the circle to white.

Comment: refer this link:  http://heliodorj.blogspot.in/2009/04/androids-statelistdrawable-example.html

Comment: Use two image  for radio button one is selected and another is not, chane this images on Radiobutton click either by using setbackground resource or by using  selector xml.

Answer (score 387, accepted):

It is simpler just setting the buttonTint color (only works on API level 21 or above):

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radio"
    android:checked="true"
    android:buttonTint="@color/your_color"/>
```

In your *values/colors.xml* file, put your color, in this case a reddish one:

```
<color name="your_color">#e75748</color>
```

Result:

[image: Colored Android Radio Button]

If you want to do it by code (also API 21 and above):

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
{
    ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]
            {
                new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // Disabled
                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled}   // Enabled
            },
            new int[]
            {
                Color.BLACK, // disabled
                Color.BLUE   // enabled
            }
        );

    radio.setButtonTintList(colorStateList); // set the color tint list
    radio.invalidate(); // Could not be necessary
}
```

Comment: @emaillenin, if you want to change the color tint by code you should use `control.getDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);` where `control` is the control you want to change the tint and `color` is an integer value of the color you want e.g.`R.color.red`

Comment: @JorgeArimany For a RadioButton, is it getButtonDrawable or getCompoundDrawables? getCompoundDrawables returns a List

Comment: @emaillenin, thank you, my answer to your comment was for other controls like a button, I've upgraded my answer by adding the code you are looking for, hope that helps you

Comment: @JorgeArimany I got it working for > 21 already.. I am looking for answers specifically for < 21

Comment: To change the color of a checked button you can add or replace a state with `android.R.attr.state_checked` and add the color.

Comment: if you want have a stroke & background for your radio button, combine the `android:buttonTint` with `android:background`

Answer (score 178):

**Update:**

1. use this one instead

   ```
   <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbtn_test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:buttonTint="@color/primary" />
   ```
2. Then add this line into parent layout or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> in Android Studio to auto-add
   `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

A *minimum example* should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbtn_test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:buttonTint="@color/primary" />

</LinearLayout>
```

3. In your program, you should call it like this:
    `AppCompatRadioButton radioButton = (AppCompatRadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.rbtn_test);`

Basically, this kind of pattern can be applied for all AppCompact types such as AppCompatCheckBox, AppCompatButton, and so on.

**Old Answer:**

In order to support below android API 21, you can use **AppCompatRadioButton.** Then use `setSupportButtonTintList` method to change the color. This is my code snippet to create a radio button.

```
    AppCompatRadioButton rb;
    rb = new AppCompatRadioButton(mContext);

    ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]{
                    new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_checked},
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked}
            },
            new int[]{

                    Color.DKGRAY
                    , Color.rgb (242,81,112),
            }
    );
    rb.setSupportButtonTintList(colorStateList);
```

Tested result at API 19:

[image: This one is tested on API 19]

See the Android [reference link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatRadioButton.html) for more detail.

Comment: This answer should be the accepted one. If you want to add this support radio button through xml, use `<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton ../>`

Comment: `setSupportButtonTintList` is a private method you are not intended to use. The radio buttons will behave oddly on certain versions of Android. Instead, use `CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(rb, colorStateList)`.

Comment: @wampastompa is right. On API 22, the result was that I saw only an outer circle, never filled when checked. @aknay; please update your answer

Comment: I am on API 16. I add the AppCompat Radio buttons as listed above, however it is still not displaying correctly.

Comment: you don't need any code, see IgorOliveira's answer. Works for all versions.

Answer (score 82):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:buttonTint="@color/Color" />
```

Comment: This is the answer for pre, current, and post lollypop devices!! Great

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Short and perfect. NOTE: use app:buttonTint="@color/Color" but not andoid:buttonTint="@color/Color" !

Comment: @KirillKarmazin accepted should be which works for <21

Comment: Still, an explanation would be in order. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35801029/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 62):

**This is working on API pre 21 as well as post 21.**

In your `styles.xml` put:

```
<!-- custom style -->
<style name="radionbutton"
       parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/radiobutton_drawable</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

Your *radio button* in XML should look like:

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    style="@style/radionbutton"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Now all you need to do is make a `radiobutton_drawable.xml` in your `drawable folder`. Here is what you need to put in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_unchecked" android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_unchecked" android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="false"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_checked" android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_checked" android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="false"/>
</selector>
```

Your *radio_unchecked.xml* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="oval">
  <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
  <size android:width="30dp" android:height="30dp"/>
</shape>
```

Your *radio_checked.xml* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
      <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
      <size android:width="30dp" android:height="30dp"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:top="5dp" android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
      <solid android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
      <size android:width="10dp" android:height="10dp"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Just replace `@color/colorAccent` with the color of your choice.

Comment: How would I do this programmatically?

Comment: @tccpg288 If you use this xml and if you want to change the color programmatically, simply use radioButton.setChecked(false) or radioButton.setChecked(true)

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: My mistake, does it matter if I use the regular RadioButton or the AppCompat RadioButton?

Comment: It is not working, what about when I initialize the RadioButton? Here is my code:             mPollAnswerArrayList.add((indexCreated), new RadioButton((getActivity().getApplicationContext()),null,R.style.radiobutton));

Comment: You can use radio button. You have set the attribute set as null. I am not sure, but maybe that is causing an issue.

Comment: I have referenced the style in the radio button xml in my answer

Comment: This solution is incredible! Just wish we would not lose the default buttons animations.

Answer (score 40):

1. Declare a custom style in your *styles.xml* file.

   ```
    <style name="MyRadioButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
      <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/indigo</item>
      <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/pink</item>
    </style>
   ```
2. Apply this style to your RadioButton via the *android:theme* attribute.

   ```
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Radio Button"
        android:theme="@style/MyRadioButton"/>
   ```

But only if your activity extends `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: This should be accepted as an answer, it works on all versions and it is cleanest

Comment: I had to use `<item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/pink</item>` for it to work for me. I'm still not sure why. Otherwise, this is a good answer.

Comment: This is a better solution when you are starting to consider light and dark themes

Answer (score 23):

**For under API 21**

Create a custom style RadioButton:

File *style.xml*

```
<style name="RadioButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/green</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/mediumGray</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

In the layout, use the theme:

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/RadioButton" />
```

---

**For API 21 and higher**

Just use *buttonTint*:

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:buttonTint="@color/green" />
```

Comment: Should be clarified: buttonTint works for API 21 **and** apps that use AppCompat/AndroidX, no matter API

Answer (score 20):

You can change the color of radio button's unchecked and checked state by using style in XML.

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/RadioButtonStyle" />
```

In style.xml

```
<style name="RadioButtonStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

You can set the desired colors in this style.

Comment: Theme inside the RadioButton doesn't work (anymore?). It crashes while clicking the button, because the onClick method is not found, although it is here.

Comment: this issue will have some other reason. Make sure you are getting the correct view's ID before implementing the onClick on that view.

Answer (score 19):

You have to use this code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Radiobutton1"
                    app:buttonTint="@color/black" />
```

Using `app:buttonTint` instead of `android:buttonTint` and also `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton` instead of `Radiobutton`!

Comment: This is the best solution! Clean, short and works on old versions.

Answer (score 12):

Set the `buttonTint` property. For example, `android:buttonTint="#99FF33"`.

Comment: This is only after API 21

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes you just need to override **colorControlNormal** like this:

```
<style name="RadioButtonStyle" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/pink</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

And you will get a button like this:

[image]

**colorControlNormal** is used for the unchecked state and **colorAccent** for checked.

Answer (score 9):

I made it the short way like this (working on API pre 21 as well as post 21):

Your radio button in XML should look like this

```
  <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radioid"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:button="@drawable/radiodraw" />
```

In file *radiodraw.xml*:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:state_checked="false" >
          <shape  android:shape="oval" >
              <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000"/>
              <size android:width="30dp" android:height="30dp"/>
              <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
          </shape>
      </item>
      <item android:state_checked="true">
          <layer-list>
              <item>
                  <shape android:shape="oval">
                      <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000"/>
                      <size android:width="30dp" android:height="30dp"/>
                      <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
                  </shape>
              </item>
              <item android:top="5dp" android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp">
                  <shape android:shape="oval">
                      <solid android:width="1dp" android:color="#000"/>
                      <size android:width="10dp" android:height="10dp"/>
                  </shape>
              </item>
          </layer-list>
      </item>
  </selector>
```

You have to add color transparent for drawing the unchecked status; else it draws a solid black oval.

Comment: That last line saves me. It's needed to add that transparency background else it will just paint all the drawable.

Answer (score 9):

For those who want to change disable, checked and enabled states you can do the following steps:

```
<!-- Or androidX radio button or material design radio button -->
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:buttonTint="@color/black"
                    android:text="Radiobutton1"
                    app:buttonTint="@color/radio_button_color" />
```

Then in the color res folder, make a file named "radio_button_color.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/yellow900" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/yellow800" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/gray800" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/yellow800" android:state_enabled="true" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 6):

There is an XML attribute for it:

```
android:buttonTint="yourcolor"
```

Comment: Make sure your min API is higher then 21 or this won't work

Comment: you can use this for backward compatibility: app:buttonTint="your_color"

Comment: `"Make sure your min API is higher then 21 or this won't work"` that is false. I'm targeting API 17 with AndroidX and this is the only thing that worked for me

Answer (score 2):

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radio"
    android:buttonTint="@color/my_color"/>
```

All buttons will change color, the circle box and the central check.

Comment: But not the ripple ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"` attribute on the <RadioButton> tag.

Answer (score 2):

create a drawable file my_compound_button_color_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/text_app_color"/>
<item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/text_app_color"/>
<item android:color="@color/gray"/> </selector>
```

add style in style.xml file

```
<style name="AppRadioAppStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/my_compound_button_color_selector</item>
    <item name="drawableTint">@drawable/my_compound_button_color_selector</item>
</style>
```

layout file

```
<RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:drawableBottom="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                    android:background="@drawable/app_border_0"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:text="@string/no"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                    style="@style/AppRadioAppStyle"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"/>
```

should be add android:button="@null" in your radiobutton

Answer (score 1):

RadioButton by default takes the colour of colorAccent in res/values/colors.xml file.
So go to that file and change the value of

`<color name="colorAccent">#3F51B5</color>`

to the colour you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way in XML with the `android:buttonTint` attribute:

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radio"
    android:checked="false"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:buttonTint="@color/radio_color"/>
```

You can do it this way in Java using `android:buttonTint`:

```
// RadioButton ColorStateList
ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
    new int[][]{
        new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // Unchecked
        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked} // Checked
    },

    new int[]{
        DataUtils.getColorResource(mContext, R.color.colorBlack), // Unchecked
        DataUtils.getColorResource(mContext, R.color.colorPrimary) // Checked
    }
);

RadioButton radio = findViewById(R.id.radio);   
radio.setButtonTintList(colorStateList);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to change  `colourAccent` color in `values->colours.xml`
but be aware that it will also change other things like edit text cursor color etc..

`< color name="colorAccent">#75aeff</color >`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. If your app has a black background and you have a lot of RadioButtons that are invisible due to the background, it is complicated to edit the `android:buttonTint` attribute of each one. The best solution is to change the parent theme in your *styles.xml* file

I changed

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

So the RadioButtons' circles became a lighter shade of gray and now they are visible even with a black background.

This is my *style.xml* file:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the radio button color programmatically you can use following:

```
yourradio button name.buttonDrawable?.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor( color_value), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
```

Answer (score 0):

use **app:buttonTint** instead of  **android:buttonTint** like this:

```
 <com.google.android.material.radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="English"
        android:checked="true"
        app:buttonTint="#FF0000"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Material3.TitleSmall"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        />
```

or

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="English"
    android:checked="true"
    app:buttonTint="#FF0000"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Material3.TitleSmall"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

For different colors according to checked and unchecked states please try this -

Create a color resource file `@color/radio_button` -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/grey" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/grey" android:state_checked="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/green" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/green" android:state_checked="true" />
</selector>
```

And then use it like this -

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:buttonTint="@color/radio_button" />
```

**Remember to replace `android:buttonTint` with `app:buttonTint` if you are using **Theme.Material3.DayNight**

Answer (score 0):

This kotlin Extension

```js
fun RadioButton.setLangRadioColor(isCheck: Boolean) {

    val color = if (isCheck) {
        intArrayOf(
            ContextCompat.getColor(rootView.context, R.color.light_red),
            ContextCompat.getColor(rootView.context, R.color.light_red)
        )
    } else {
        intArrayOf(
            ContextCompat.getColor(rootView.context, R.color.sortRadioUnselectColor),
            ContextCompat.getColor(rootView.context, R.color.sortRadioUnselectColor)
        )
    }

    val colorStateList = ColorStateList(
        arrayOf(
            intArrayOf(-android.R.attr.state_enabled), // disabled
            intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_enabled)  // enabled
        ),
        color
    )
    this.buttonTintList = colorStateList
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set different color for a clicked and unclicked radio button, just use:

`android:buttonTint="@drawable/radiobutton"` in the XML content of the radiobutton and your *radiobutton.xml* file will be:

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#1E88E5"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#00e676"/>
    <item android:color="#ffffff"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: android:buttonTint accept only colours

Answer (score -1):

If you have `android:buttonTint` it wont work and you have to change it to `app:buttonTint`.
I had to do this after uprading to androidx.

Answer (score -4):

@jh314 is correct.

In file *AndroidManifest.xml*,

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></application>
```

In file *style.xml*:

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/red</item>
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

The item name must be colorAccent. It decides the application's widgets default color.

But if you want to change the color in code, maybe @aknay's answer is correct.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11765418)

Comment: My answer is change the app's basic color and of course it can change radiobutton's color to white.