# Android RadioButton textColor selector

Tags: android, radio-button

I have a selector for `textColor` of a `RadioButton` like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#fff"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#f00"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#0f0"/>
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#00f"/>
</selector>
```

I expected that the one selected `RadioButton` will have different color than the others.

However, all of the `RadioButton`s have blue text (using android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"), even the one that is selected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It looks like you're just using the wrong selectors.  The docs describe selecting as follows:

> During each state change, the state list is traversed top to bottom and the first item that matches the current state is used—the selection is not based on the "best match," but simply the first item that meets the minimum criteria of the state.

[Source link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

So, in order:

1. state_selected is never true as RadioButtons use state_checked
   when checked.
2. state_focused is never called because RadioButton
   will never receive input focus.
3. state_pressed should be working. 
   When you hold your finger down you don't see the text appearing
   green?
4. state_focused false and state_pressed false ends up being
   default so you see blue.

If you would like to see different states, try these:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#0f0"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#fff"/>
    <item android:color="#00f"/>
</selector>
```

I have tested the above and can see all colors being expressed appropriately.

Comment: setting this selector as background for RadioButton will it work ?. I am not able set as RadioButton background.

Comment: Yes, setting this as your background should work.  If the above were in "drawable/radiobutton_background.xml" then you would add it as follows: "android:background="@drawable/radiobutton_background".

Comment: @Ramesh_D Yes it is. `#778899` can also be `#789`. Values just take double places when rendered.

Answer (score 31):

According to Android. 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html

You have to create a folder called 'color' in 'res' directory and create a new file called radiobuttonstate.xml for example which it looks like this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_focused="true"
    android:color="YOUR COLOR" />

   <item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_enabled="false"
    android:color="YOUR COLOR" />

    <item android:color="YOUR COLOR"
    android:state_checked="true"/>

    <item
    android:state_enabled="false"
    android:color="YOUR COLOR" />

   <item android:color="YOUR COLOR" />
</selector>
```

then in your radio button define in the android:textColor attribute your color list you previously defined.

```
  <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_H"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/string_example"
                    android:textColor="@color/radiobuttonstate"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Answer (score 15):

The answer provided by @GrantAmos is perfect and working. If you want to text color selector through XML, please use this code.

`android:textColor="@color/textview_selector"`

However, if you want to set the selector programmatically, use this code -

```
radioButton.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getContext(), R.color.textview_selector));
```

Hope it will save someone's time.

Answer (score 4):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@color/dark_grey"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/topic_green"/>
</selector>
```

This one works for me. Actually when i use android:color="@color/dark_grey". It didn't work. But when i changed to drawable it did.

Answer (score -1):

```
<style name="MyRadioButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/lbl_login</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/btn_login_back_color</item>
</style>

 <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_radio_credit_card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/_14ssp"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_1sdp"
        android:text="Credit Card"
        android:textColor="@color/lbl_login"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"
        android:theme="@style/MyRadioButton" />
```

[Refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120199/change-circle-color-of-radio-button)