# How to change the circle color of the radio button programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-radiobutton

I have a RadioGroup that will be populated programmatically (I'm using kotlin) and I want to change the circle color of the radio button (try to avoid the accent color solution).

** **XML**

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radio_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp" />
```

** **Kotlin**

```
for (entry in entries) {

    val rb = RadioButton(applicationContext)

    rb .text = entry
    rb .id = entries.indexOf(entry) + 100
    rb .setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
    rb .isChecked = (entries.indexOf(entry) == 0)

    rbg.addView(rb)
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852253/how-to-change-checked-color-of-radio-button-programmatically or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120199/change-circle-color-of-radio-button or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212120/how-to-programatically-set-the-colour-of-a-radiobutton-android-circle don't thank me ;-)

Comment: IT works fine for api > 21 but I consider api 16

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
android:buttonTint="your color"
```

For API<21

```
app:buttonTint="your color"
```

to change the color of circle in RadioButton

Comment: Edited my answer, check now

Comment: I said "programmatically"