# How to change checked color of Radio Button programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to know if its possible programmatically and how to change programmatically the color of RadioButton when it checked ?

PS : I dont want to use XML

in XML I use something like this and its work :

```
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test1"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/CustomColorRadioButton" />
```

In my style.xml

```
<style name="CustomRadioButton" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

How can I do that programmatically ?

Comment: radioButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.yourColor));

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't change Radio Button color on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28307512/cant-change-radio-button-color-on-android)

Comment: This one use XML , i dont want to use it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
        new int[][]{
                new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, //disabled
                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled} //enabled
        },
        new int[] {
                Color.BLACK, //disabled
                Color.BLUE //enabled
        }
    );

radio.setButtonTintList(colorStateList);
```

See: [Change Circle color of radio button- Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120199/change-circle-color-of-radio-button-android)

Comment: Check you just change state_enabled by state_checked and its good ;) thanks

Comment: It helped me also. I think it works only for SDK above 20