# AppCompatCheck Box not visible in android 4.3 API 18

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-checkbox

I am using AppCompatCheckBox in XML layout as given below,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:buttonTint="@color/appColor"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp" />
```

But the check box is not visible on device running 4.3. But CheckBox text is visible, but not the CheckBox. Whats wrong here?

I am following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120199/change-circle-color-of-radio-button-android). See the answer with 5 Points.

Comment: That worked on `Lollipop` + `Kitkat 4.4.2`, have you tried that on an another api ?

Comment: Yes it works on both. I tried that

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know if this solves, but you don’t need to use `AppCompatCheckBox`; a simple `CheckBox` is enough.

The activity you are using, presumably an `AppCompatActivity`, automatically inflates layout checkboxes as `AppCompatCheckBox`s.

`AppCompat*` widgets should be used only when creating views at runtime, e.g. `new AppCompatCheckBox(context)` or when subclassing.