# set my own color of radio button in menu option items

Tags: android

I want to change the circle color of radio button (now is pink, (see the image below)) to dark blue for all items of menu.

[image]

That's my menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.aoutir.mohamed.movies.MainFragment"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <!--<item-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/action_refresh"-->
    <!--android:title="@string/Refresh"-->
    <!--android:orderInCategory="200"/>-->
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_popular"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="@string/action_popular"
            app:showAsAction="never" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_rated"
            android:orderInCategory="200"
            android:title="@string/action_rated"
            app:showAsAction="never" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_favourites"
            android:orderInCategory="300"
            android:title="@string/action_favourites"
            app:showAsAction="never" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

style.xml (here is my style of whole application):

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <!--<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>-->
    </style>

    <!--<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">-->
        <!--<item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>-->
        <!--<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>-->
        <!--<item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>-->
    <!--</style>-->

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MovieTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Movies.NoTitle</item>
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonOverflow</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Movies.NoTitle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
        <item name="logo">@mipmap/pop_corn</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >
        <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
        <item name="android:overlapAnchor" tools:ignore="NewApi">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    </style>

    <style name="CircularProgress" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/sky_blue</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionButtonOverflow" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:src">@mipmap/ic_sort</item>
        <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/action_sort</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

and java code that is associated to my menu (check if item is selected and do some action):

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_fragment_menu,menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_popular:
                if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
                else item.setChecked(true);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_rated:
                if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
                else item.setChecked(true);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_favourites:
                if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
                else item.setChecked(true);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29551017/8448886

Comment: Try: `app:itemIconTint="@color/black"` for radio items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To style the radio buttons inside your overflow menu's popup window, you can set `colorAccent` (for the selected radio button) and `colorControlNormal` (for the other buttons) in your toolbar's *popup theme*.

First, create a `<style>` to use as the theme:

```
<style name="MyPopupTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">#00f</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#00f</item>
</style>
```

Then, set this style as your `app:popupTheme` in your layout, on whatever `Toolbar` you're using for your activity's action bar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    app:popupTheme="@style/MyPopupTheme"
    .../>
```

Comment: Yeah did not work for me when I am using PopupMenu(ContextThemeWrapper(ctx, R.style.CustomPopupStyle), view) to create the menu

Answer (score 1):

Use this `<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton` for your own color on radio button :

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:buttonTint="@color/Color" />
```

Or, you can use style for this :

```
<style name="RadioButtonStyle" parent="AppTheme">
   <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/pink</item>
   <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
   <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/black</item>
</style>
```