# Change the color of radioButon when one of the options is selected in Android

Tags: android, android-radiobutton, android-radiogroup

I have developed a dynamic UI of survey questions, where I have questions answering "YES" or "NO". For questions having answers as Yes/No, I have taken radio-group for user input. How to change the color of the Radio button Highlight color for a specific question , when a specific radioGroup option(Yes/no) is selected everytime? I have Done the following implementation, but it is not working.

```
 final AppCompatRadioButton[] rb = new AppCompatRadioButton[2];
 final RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(context); //create the RadioGroup
 rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);//or RadioGroup.VERTICAL
 String[] options = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.radio_options_yes_no);

   if (questionList.get(j).getQuestionId().matches("3|16|24"))
   {                    
        rb[0].setHighlightColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        rb[0].setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
   }

   //for yes as unsafe option
   else if (questionList.get(j).getQuestionId().matches("21|23|30|32")){
         rb[1].setHighlightColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
         rb[1].setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
   }
```

Comment: I don't see any question nor errors posted here

Comment: not able to understand what you are saying

Comment: I have done the necessary edit along with my code implementation. Sorry for less information, as this was my first posted question over stackoverflow :) ;) @ashad

Comment: have a look  [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120199/change-circle-color-of-radio-button-android)

Answer (score 0):

add this onclick on all radio button in xml

```
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
```

now add onRadioButtonCliked method

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
// Is the button now checked?
boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

// Check which radio button was clicked
switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.radio_pirates:
        if (checked)
            // Pirates are the best
        break;
    case R.id.radio_ninjas:
        if (checked)
            // Ninjas rule
        break;
}
```

}

now apply your logic here 
and change the color  using this code

```
.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

[here is the link for further reading](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton#java) 
[for  radio button circle color change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120199/change-circle-color-of-radio-button-android)

Comment: I want to change the radio button circle color ,not the text color.@ashad