# Android : change button text and background color

Tags: android, button, colors, background, status

How can I change both text and background colors when my button is pressed, with xml ?

To change text color I can do :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="mycolor"/>
    <item android:color="mycolor2"/>
</selector>
```

To change the background I can do (using it in a selector/item with drawable reference) :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FF0079FF" />
</shape>
```

But how can I do both ? Let's say I want to have :

- Default : black text / white background
- Pressed : white text / blue background

#### EDIT : answer

I totaly forgot that the background and text color are managed separately, so this is how I did it :

```
<Button
    android:textColor="@color/filtersbuttoncolors"
    android:background="@drawable/mybackgroundcolors" />
```

In mybackgroundcolors.xml I manage the background and in filtersbuttoncolors.xml I manage the text color. In both xml files I manage the status (pressed, selected, default)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16213334/1567588

Comment: can't we do it without 9patch ?

Comment: Yes. we can. I see that you have got an answer. Happy coding..

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here is an example of a drawable that will be white by default, black when pressed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#1E669B"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#1B5E91"/>
            <corners
                android:radius="6dp"/>
            <padding
                android:bottom="10dp"
                android:left="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"/>
        </shape>

    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="#1E669B"
                android:startColor="#1E669B"/>
            <stroke
                android:width="4dp"
                android:color="#1B5E91"/>
            <corners
                android:radius="7dp"/>
            <padding
                android:bottom="10dp"
                android:left="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Ok but what will change the text color ? Do I have to use 9patch for the background ?

Comment: You can change the textcolor programatically.. or through style.xml

Comment: omg you are right ... I didn't though about it. Thank I update my topic to give the answer

Comment: done it of course, I also add the explaination in my question

Answer (score 58):

Since API level 21 you can use :

```
android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
```

you only have to add this in your xml

Comment: This is a much better solution, I dono why android made it so complex to just change a button background color. And keep the default behaviour.

Comment: @Bhaskara you can use support libraries `app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"`

Comment: I browsed through a ton of methods how to override in XML the default button background color specified in a theme and only this one worked.

Answer (score 28):

I think doing this way is much simpler:

```
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

And you need to `import android.graphics.Color;` not: `import android.R.color;`

Or you can just write the 4-byte hex code (not 3-byte) `0xFF000000` where the first byte is setting the alpha.

Comment: This will loose the color of the button when you select it, and will also loose any shading or shapes which the theme implys on the button.

Comment: Also it is hardcoding a value, which should themed.

Answer (score 21):

Just complementing @Jonsmoke's answer.

For API level 21 and above you can use :

```
android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
```

in XML for the button layout.

For API level below 21 use an **AppCompatButton** using **app** namespace instead of **android** for *backgroundTint*.

For example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/my_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My Button"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white" />
```

Comment: Thanks was looking for a pre-21 solution

Answer (score 14):

add below line in styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.Gray" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorGray</item>
    </style>
```

in button, add `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Gray"`, example:

```
<Button
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Gray"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@android:string/cancel"/>
```

Comment: I tried the same thing but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 4):

When you create an App, a file called styles.xml will be created in your res/values folder. If you change the styles, you can change the background, text color, etc for all your layouts. That way you don’t have to go into each individual layout and change the it manually.

styles.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="Theme.AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:editTextColor">#295055</item> 
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#295055</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#295055</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">#295055</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">#295055</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">#295055</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiaryInverse">#295055</item>

     <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/custom_background</item>        
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

`parent="@android:style/Theme.Light"` is Google’s native colors. Here is a reference of what the native styles are:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml

`name="Theme.AppBaseTheme"` means that you are creating a style that inherits all the styles from `parent="@android:style/Theme.Light"`.
This part you can ignore unless you want to inherit from AppBaseTheme again. =     `<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">`

@drawable/custom_background is a custom image I put in the drawable’s folder. It is a 300x300 png image.

#295055 is a dark blue color.

My code changes the background and text color. For Button text, please look through Google’s native stlyes (the link I gave u above).

Then in Android Manifest, remember to include the code:

```
<application
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppBaseTheme">
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use a **MaterialButton** and the `app:backgroundTint` and `android:textColor` attributes:

```
<MaterialButton
  app:backgroundTint="@color/my_color"
  android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

add below lines in the styles.xml

```xml
<style name="AppTheme.Gray" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorGray</item>
</style>
```

and in button, add android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Gray", example:

```xml
    <Button
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Gray"
      android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@android:string/cancel"/>
```