# Change the Color of RadioButton When Clicked

Tags: android, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I have a **`RadioGroup`** having 3 **`Radio Buttons`**. By default , when I click the radio button, it turns **Blue**. I need to change the color, say , when I click the first one, it should turn to **Yellow**, the 2nd one **Blue** and the 3rd one to **Green**.

I have seen some tutorials to customize by styling the radio buttons, like [Is it possible to change the radio button icon in an android radio button group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576507/is-it-possible-to-change-the-radio-button-icon-in-an-android-radio-button-group) but it hides all the buttons.

[image]

Here is my XML .

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/studentImage"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/studentImage"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/studentImage"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: You can try [this](http://heliodorj.blogspot.in/2009/04/androids-statelistdrawable-example.html) with different selectors for all radio-buttons.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213186/how-to-change-border-color-of-radio-button-in-android

Comment: @PerlDeveloper, Thnx for the link, it worked for me.

Comment: @Aleena I'm after the same information. Could you please advise on how to achieve this? PearlDeveloper seems to have deleted the comment you found useful...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a statelist drawable like I wrote below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/color_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/default_button" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

color_pressed and deafult_button would be your drawables for each button's state, you could have multiple selectors for each radio button

Comment: When i apply the this style to my radio button like **`android:button="@drawable/radio"`**  , it hides the buttons.