# Android: Change the color of RadioButtons and checkboxes programmatically

Tags: android, checkbox, colors, radio-button

I created `RadioButton` and `CheckBox` in `LinearLayout` programatically. But, now I want to change radio button's color and check boxes's color. I use

`RadioButton.setHighlightColor(Color.parseColor("#0c83bd"));`

`checkbox.setHighlightColor(Color.parseColor("#0c83bd"));`

But it didn't work.

Comment: use background images

Comment: but i want to set color not to attach images

Comment: is there any function available in android support library?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this

```
AppCompatRadioButton newRadioButton = new AppCompatRadioButton(this);
AppCompatCheckBox newCheckBox = new AppCompatCheckBox(this);
```

Insted of

```
RadioGroup newRadioButton = new RadioGroup(this);
CheckBox newCheckBox = new CheckBox(this);
```

Answer (score 22):

Use **AppCompatCheckBox** and **AppCompatRadioButton** instead of **CheckBox** and **RadioButton**.
**Your xml will have :**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cbSelected"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent" //This to set your default button color
    android:checked="true"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rb"
    app:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent" //This to set your default button color
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Now for the java code : 
Create **ColorStateList**

```
        ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]{
                        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled} //enabled
                },
                new int[] {getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary) }
        );
```

To change the color programatically for **AppCompatRadioButton** or **AppCompatCheckBox** call **setSupportButtonTintList**.

```
AppCompatRadioButton radioButton = (AppCompatRadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb);
radioButton.setSupportButtonTintList(colorStateList);

AppCompatCheckBox cbSelected = (AppCompatCheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbSelected);
cbSelected.setSupportButtonTintList(colorStateList);
```

Answer (score 16):

You can create dynamic `RadioButton` like this:

```
RadioButton male = new RadioButton(ReservationContact.this);
male.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
male.setText("Male");
male.setSelected(true);
male.setId(0);
```

This is used for changing default color of circle of `RadioButton`.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    male.setButtonTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(ReservationContact.this, R.color.background)));
}
male.setHighlightColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.background));
```

Answer (score 7):

For `CheckBox`, replace your `CheckBox` with `AppCompatCheckBox` and call following method:

```
public static void setCheckBoxColor(AppCompatCheckBox checkBox, int uncheckedColor, int checkedColor) {
    ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
            new int[][] {
                    new int[] { -android.R.attr.state_checked }, // unchecked
                    new int[] {  android.R.attr.state_checked }  // checked
            },
            new int[] {
                    uncheckedColor,
                    checkedColor
            }
    );
    checkBox.setSupportButtonTintList(colorStateList);
}
```

I think it should be similar for `RadioButton`. You can check declared attributes in `android.R.attr` and change the code.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried a couple of ways to achieve it programmatically but none worked for me except following. Dropping it here, in case someone finds it helpful.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null" />
```

Create a ColorStateList

```
private fun getRadioButtonColor(): ColorStateList {
    val states = arrayOf(
            intArrayOf(-android.R.attr.state_checked),
            intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_checked))

    val colors = intArrayOf(
            ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.grey2),
            ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.actionBlue)
    )

    return ColorStateList(states, colors)
}
```

And then use **setButtonTintList** from **CompoutButtonCompat** class to set this colorStateList

```
CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(radio_btn, getRadioButtonColor())
```

Answer (score 0):

I am continuing the answer of ywwynm.

Google made the setSupportButtonTintList restricted so it is not possible to use it.

The workaround is to use the button as a TintableCompoundButton interface, in which the method is not restricted.

Works in API 19+ for AppCompatRadioButton. AppCompatCheckbox implements the same interface so it should work as well in theory but I haven't tested it.

Have fun :)

```
public static void setAppCompatRadioButtonColor(AppCompatRadioButton radioButton, int uncheckedColor, int checkedColor) {
    ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
            new int[][] {
                    new int[] { -android.R.attr.state_checked }, // unchecked
                    new int[] {  android.R.attr.state_checked }  // checked
            },
            new int[] {
                    uncheckedColor,
                    checkedColor
            }
    );
    ((TintableCompoundButton) radioButton).setSupportButtonTintList(colorStateList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line:

```
app:buttonTint="@color/yellow"
```

**Example in your xml:**

```
 <RadioButton
      android:id="@+id/radio"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:buttonTint="@color/yellow"
      android:text=" Radio"
      android:textColor="@color/yellow" />
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   RadioButton rb=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
    rb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            rb.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.image);
            rb.setHighlightColor(Color.parseColor("#0c83bd"));


        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: What if the user sets its own OnCheckedChangeListener?