# I want change radio button color depending on it's id

Tags: android

I want change radio button color depending on it's id.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set to the radio buttons the same attribute (in the UI layout)

```
android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
```

and in the code you can change the colors.

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {

// Is the button now checked?
boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

// Check which radio button was clicked
switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.radio_1:
        if (checked)
            // change color
        break;
    case R.id.radio_2:
        if (checked)
            // change color
        break;
}
```

}

Have a look:

- [Change color of a radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696275/change-color-of-a-radio-button/29550782#29550782)
- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html