# SearchView.clearFocus can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support)

Tags: android, android-lint

I have a searchview defined in an activity as follows:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;

public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @BindView(R.id.search_view) SearchView searchView;

  private void setupSearchView() {
      SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
      searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
      searchView.setIconified(false);          
      searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
          searchView.clearFocus();
          return true;
        }

        @Override public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
          searchFor(s);
          return true;
        }
      });
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
androidBuildToolsVersion = "25.0.2"
androidMinSdkVersion = 16
androidTargetSdkVersion = 25
androidCompileSdkVersion = 25
supportVersion = '25.1.0'
```

Upon analysing(Analyze -> Inspect code) **lint** tool reports the following issue:

> SearchView.clearFocus can only be called from within the same library
>   group (groupId=com.android.support)

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, could anyone provide me a solution?

Comment: its a google issue. [Duplicate question here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41251316/6801299)