# Using Precondition.checkNotNull() in Android Studio 3.0 gives lint error

Tags: android, java-8, android-studio-3.0, android-gradle-3.0

I have recently updated my Android Studio to 3.0.  I tried using Preconditions.checkNotNull() but it shows an error with following message.

**Preconditions.checkNotNull() can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support).**

I searched some other links and found something similar happening when older support library versions were rolled out.

[AppCompatActivity.onCreate can only be called from within the same library group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150995/appcompatactivity-oncreate-can-only-be-called-from-within-the-same-library-group)

Suggested answers tells me to disable lint warnings but I don't think it's the right thing to do in the long run.

Any explanation on why this particular error shows up?

Comment: That's an internal API, which is not available publicly, you cannot/shouldn't use that (without using reflection of course).

Comment: I thought so. It is available in android.support.v4.util package while I assume is available for us to use right?

Comment: Use `Objects.nonNull()` instead

Comment: @Lino, it can only be used for targetSdkVersion 19 or greater right. I need somthing backwards compatible till api level 16.Only If there is something.

Comment: import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull;

Comment: did you find your answer?if you did put it here tnx

Answer (score 0):

Use **androidx** instead.

```
import androidx.core.util.Preconditions;

ref = Preconditions.checkNotNull(anotherRef);
```

Comment: Getting error for this also. 
"Preconditions can only be called from within the same library group prefix (referenced groupId=androidx.core "

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inline function:

```kotlin
requireNotNull
```

This does not show a warning like `Preconditions.checkNotNull(ref)`