# Android P visibilityawareimagebutton.setVisibility can only be called from the same library group

Tags: android, kotlin, android-9.0-pie, android-jetpack

I'm trying to use the new Android P FloatingActionButton that's part of the `com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton` and I'm getting this warning:

> VisibilityAwareImageButton.setVisibility can only be called from the same library group (groupId=com.google.android.material)

```
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import android.view.View

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var demoFab: FloatingActionButton

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        demoFab = findViewById(R.id.demoFab)
        demoFab.visibility = View.VISIBLE  // the warning is here
    }
}
```

[image]

I've tried searching and the only search result is in regards to responding to UI visibility changes:

[Respond to UI visibility changes](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility)

I tried exploring how I could to see if there was a `VISIBLE` int value in that `com.google.android.material` package and the only one I found was `com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.VISIBLE`, but the warning still remains.

### Top-level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha14'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.gms:oss-licenses:0.9.2"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

### Project-level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.oss.licenses.plugin'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.codeforsanjose.maps.pacmap"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 'P'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'x86', 'x86_64'
            universalApk false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha2'

    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.5.2'
    //implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.1.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer:0.5.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.13.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.13.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-oss-licenses:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.4.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.2.0'
}
```

#### edit:

I should note that I'm using Android Studio version 3.2 canary 14. It seems there have been some reported bugs for this version, and I suspect this is one of them.

### edit 2:

Issue still exists with Android Studio version 3.2 canary 15, but I found a workaround for it using `show()` and `hide()`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    demoFab = findViewById(R.id.demoFab)
    demoFab.show()    // this works and doesn't have the warning
}
```

Comment: Correct package is android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

Comment: With Android P and Jetpack, the Fab was moved to this package, that's the one I'm trying to use. https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/FloatingActionButton.html

Comment: @KyleFalconer Canary 15 is now available, check if the update can fix your problem :)

Comment: @PankajKumar Yup, still broken, but I did find another workaround for it (added "edit 2" to my question).

Comment: This issue describes the bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115924750
Unfortunately, there is no solution or fix atm, so probably every one that is affected should star it.

Comment: I have the same problem when using Android Studio 3.5.2 / target API = 29 / AndroidX (library `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`)

Answer (score 277, accepted):

Using Method 1

```
demoFab.show(); // in place of visible
demoFab.hide(); // in place of Invisible suppress the warning/error for me.
```

and Method 2

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi") // also suppressed the warning
private void setUp() {
    ....
}
```

update:

Method 3:

```
demoFab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
demoFab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
demoFab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Method 4:

```
demoFab.visibility = View.GONE
demoFab.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
demoFab.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

Comment: hi, is there GONE and INVISIBLE methods?

Comment: Using .show() can remove the warning, but there's one problem: 
if the FAB has set,for example in XML, android:alpha="0.5" for transparency, the transparency not working then. How to fix this problem? 
Instead, I will prefer to use demoFab.visibility = View.VISIBLE if .show() can't work on android:alpha

Comment: methods show and hide are perfect for standard floating action buttons.

Answer (score 10):

Seems to work fine just to cast it to a view.

`(mFloatingActionButton as View).visibility = INVISIBLE`

Of course you need to remember that the visibility may affect other components, so you should probably use `show()` and `hide()` at the same time to make sure other components are notified of the change.

Comment: what about if i want to set visibility to GONE instead of INVISIBLE?

Comment: @charlie What difference do you expect between GONE and INVISIBLE from a floating action button? A fab usually lies above the rest of the layout so it doesn't take any space.

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
 myButton.hide();
 myClearButton.hide();
```

A typical example would be:

Hiding and showing buttons when user is typing or has focus on a EditText resource:

check if user is typing or has focus:

```
 mCommentField.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                //user has focused
                showBts();

            } else {
                //focus has stopped perform your desired action
                hideButtons();
            }
        }


    });
```

Hide and Show button methods:

```
private void hideButtons() {

    mCommentButton.hide();
    mClearButton.hide();
}

private void showBts() {

    mCommentButton. show();
    mClearButton.show();
```

And in your xml, set the buttons to invisible by default so that they only display/show when a user has focus or is typing:

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

Best practice:

```
 android:visibility="Gone"
```

Using visibility gone means your view is doesn't take up any space on your layout while "invisible" will take up unnecessary space on your layout

In this example:My Views are in a ViewHolder and iam referencing the buttons from a a fragment with a recylerview

Answer (score 3):

This also works:

```
findViewById(R.id.fab).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Yes it does.I was using a fragment in my example:setVisibility(View.GONE); does not always work in fragments especially when you have declared your views in a viewHolder that's in a separate class of its own and you are merely referencing from the Viewholder.

Answer (score 1):

For me above methods did not work so I created an extension function to make it work.

```
fun View.showView() {
    this.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}

fun View.hideView() {
    this.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

now call like

```
binding.fabAdded.showView()
```

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin I have an extension method

```
fun viewsVisibility(visibility: Int, vararg views: View) {
    for (view in views) { view.visibility = visibility }
}
```

Then in then in the code you can do the following

```
viewsVisibility(View.VISIBLE, demoFab) 
viewsVisibility(View.GONE, demoFab)
viewsVisibility(View.INVISIBLE, demoFab, addFab, removeFab)
```

The error will be gone and this gives the flexibility for any visibility state along with taking in a list of views to handle. There are a lot of times I need to handle more than one view at a time as shown in the final example line.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(data){
            fragmentPendingApprovalDetailsBinding.fabPendingList.show();
        }else {
            fragmentPendingApprovalDetailsBinding.fabPendingList.hide();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For `com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton`

Visibility

Use the show and hide methods to animate the visibility of a FloatingActionButton. The show animation grows the widget and fades it in, while the hide animation shrinks the widget and fades it out.

Source: https://material.io/develop/android/components/floating-action-button/

For `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`
use `setVisibility()` Method