# How to make floating action button invisible?

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button, material-components-android, material-components

I've declared a `FloatingActionButton` and I want it to appear only when the app is accessed by admin, so I need to make it visible(as I made it by default invisible).

I tried using `.setVisibility`, but it says `.setVisibility` can only be called from within the same library.

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/add_event_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/add_icon1"
    />
```

Comment: can you elaborate your project structure? does it contain multiple module?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343634/android-p-visibilityawareimagebutton-setvisibility-can-only-be-called-from-the-s

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [official doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/FloatingActionButton.md#visibility):

> Use the **`show`** and **`hide`** methods to animate the visibility of a `FloatingActionButton`. The show animation grows the widget and fades it in, while the hide animation shrinks the widget and fades it out.

Just use:

```
FloatingActionButton fab1 = findViewById(R.id.add_event_btn);
fab1.show();
```

Also, in the **version 1.1.0** the method `setVisibility` is not [restricted](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/2fdb73de6e39cee1ad46674ee713d9e86b4cfe06#diff-8d8a01fe2d35bf4b6d635cdf4f7a6daf).

You can use:

```
fab1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try getting a reference to your floating action button in your code, lets say its `mFab`, and do this:

`mFab.setVisibility = View.INVISIBLE`

or

`mFab.setVisibility = View.GONE`

Comment: The code is incorrect and also tries and fails to do what op originally tried.