# Calendar View show/gone inside Recyclerview ViewHolder Issue on Android 8, 9 only

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, visibility

I have a recyclerview with 2 or more viewholders,

1. 1st Viewholder is just top heading banner
2. 2nd vlewholder is for booking widget which has 3 dropdowns/detail menus including `CalendarView` -- All in one viewhodler.

Issue is CalendarView is quite big in height and when the CalendarView is slightly off the screen and I collapse/gone the calendar it is collapsing but still taking space just like below screenshots. But Strange thing is that its occurring only in **`Android 8 & 9`**.

**Initial Screenshot:**

[image]

**Issue Screenshot (After Collapsing CV):**

[image]

### Relevant Code is below:

**Viewholder Item's ClickListener:**

```
    val clickListener = View.OnClickListener {
        // irrelevant code //
        for (type in AllOptionsEnum.values()) {
                // Expand Selected and Collapse Others
            val detailView = this.root.findViewById<ViewGroup>(type.detailViewGroupId)
            val labelView = this.root.findViewById<TextView>(type.labelViewId)
            val checkBox = this.root.findViewById<CheckBox>(type.checkBoxId)

            if (detailView.visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
                // hide detailed view
                detailView.setVisible(show = false)
                checkBox.isChecked = false
            } else {
                // show
                detailView.setVisible(show = (type.labelViewGroupId == it.id))
                checkBox.isChecked = show = (type.labelViewGroupId == it.id)
                
            }
                
        // irrelevant code //
        }
    }
```

**Edit 1:**
Extension Func:

```
    fun View.setVisible(show: Boolean = true, invisible: Boolean = false) {
        if (show) this.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        else this.visibility = if (invisible) View.INVISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
```

**Edit 2:**

> I have tried another solution i.e. to remove the recyclerview completely and re-constructed the whole screen using nestedscrollview but it also has same effects.

**Edit 3:**

I have tried below code also but same result

```
                // show detailView
                if(type==Enums.StayWithUsWidgetType.TYPE_CALENDAR){
                    // show detailview and children
                    this.calendarDetailView.children.forEach {
                        it.visible()
                    }
                }


                // Hide detailView and children 
                if(type==Enums.StayWithUsWidgetType.TYPE_CALENDAR){
                    // hide all
                    this.calendarDetailView.children.forEach {
                        it.gone()
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how [Android Pie (2018)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Pie) is handling visibility changes in layouts, particularly with the CalendarView which has a complex layout hierarchy.

But do note that "[Android P visibilityawareimagebutton.setVisibility can only be called from the same library group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54408124/6309)" is clear:

> Best practice: `android:visibility="Gone"`
>
> Using visibility gone means your view is does not take up any space on your layout while "invisible" will take up unnecessary space on your layout

So double-check your `detailView.setVisible()` function. Ideally, it should look like:

```kotlin
fun View.setVisible(show: Boolean) {
    this.visibility = if (show) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```

So, when you see `setVisible(show = false)`, it is equivalent to setting [`visibility = View.GONE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#GONE) on that view. This is, however, an assumption, as the implementation of this method is not provided in your question.

---

A possible alternative solution to test would be to wrap the `CalendarView` in another layout such as `LinearLayout` or `FrameLayout`, and then set the visibility of this wrapper layout instead of the `CalendarView` itself.
That might help ensure the layout is redrawn correctly when visibility changes.

For example:

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/calendarViewContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In your click listener, you would now toggle visibility of `calendarViewContainer` instead of `calendarView`:

```kotlin
val detailView = this.root.findViewById<ViewGroup>(if (type == AllOptionsEnum.CALENDAR) R.id.calendarViewContainer else type.detailViewGroupId)
```

If the problem still persists, another workaround is to use `requestLayout()` method after changing the visibility to `GONE`. That will tell the Android system to measure and layout the view hierarchy again, which might fix your issue.

```kotlin
detailView.setVisible(show = false)
detailView.requestLayout()
```

That is not the most efficient way since it could lead to unnecessary layout passes, but it might be necessary to work around this specific issue on Android Pie (9).

---

Regarding Edit 3:

> ```kotlin
> // hide detailView
> if(type==Enums.StayWithUsWidgetType.TYPE_CALENDAR){
>     // hide detailview and children
>     this.calendarDetailView.children.forEach {
>         it.visible()
>     }
> }
> // Hide detailView and children 
> if(type==Enums.StayWithUsWidgetType.TYPE_CALENDAR){
>     // hide all
>     this.calendarDetailView.children.forEach {
>         it.gone()
>     }
> }
> ```

I see you are attempting to hide each child of the `calendarDetailView` (which I assume is the `ViewGroup` that contains your `CalendarView`) individually. However, it is still not clear if you are setting the visibility of the `calendarDetailView` itself to `GONE`.

I would prefer to see this code, where the `calendarDetailView` itself is also set to `GONE`:

```kotlin
if(type == Enums.StayWithUsWidgetType.TYPE_CALENDAR){
    // hide all children
    this.calendarDetailView.children.forEach {
        it.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    // then hide the parent itself
    this.calendarDetailView.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

Comment: `fun View.setVisible(show: Boolean = true, invisible: Boolean = false) {
            if (show) this.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            else this.visibility = if (invisible) View.INVISIBLE else View.GONE
        }`

I have added the above method in answer as well. my method looks like this.

Comment: @NadeemIqbal Did you try, in that fun, to do a `detailView.parent.requestLayout()`, to request a layout from the parent view?

Comment: @NadeemIqbal I have edited the answer to propose an alternative solution.

Comment: I have tried with Nestedscrollview and same results. will try with your solution and will update.

Comment: :( not working. See Edit 3. @VonC

Comment: @NadeemIqbal I have edited the answer to address your Edit 3.

Comment: Not working. same result. @VonC

Answer (score 0):

You can try with setting the Calenderview height programatically like below that can help you in showing extra space of that view.

```
if(type==Enums.StayWithUsWidgetType.TYPE_CALENDAR){
                    // setup height when needed
                    this.calendarDetailView.children.forEach {
                        calendarDetailView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT));
                    }
                }
```

Comment: not working :(.