# menuBuilder.setOptionalIconsVisible can only be called from within the same library group

Tags: java, android, android-menu

I am trying to show icons with overflow menu with below codes

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu,menu);

if(menu instanceof MenuBuilder){
    MenuBuilder menuBuilder = (MenuBuilder) menu;
    menuBuilder.setOptionalIconsVisible(true);
}
```

It gives me this error

> menuBuilder.setOptionalIconsVisible can only be called from within the same library group

on line

```
menuBuilder.setOptionalIconsVisible(true);
```

I know I can suppress it for ignore but I want know why its coming and there any another way to fix it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PopupMenu, you can call setForceShowIcon method to show the icons with text in the menu item.

Java:-

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
popup.setForceShowIcon(true);
```

Xml:-

```
<menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_1"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_1"
            android:title="Action 1"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_2"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_2"
            android:title="Action 2"/>
    
    </menu>
```

Answer (score -5):

**Edit**

Ok, after investigating more on the subject this seems to be a bug as stated in comment and answers to **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150995/appcompatactivity-oncreate-can-only-be-called-from-within-the-same-library-group)** and should be safe to suppress it. It may be fixed in one of the next releases of support libraries.

---

**OLD ANSWER**

Why not make menu items visible in XML? Use attribute `android:showAsAction`. There are several values available: `ifroom | always | collapseActionView | never | withText` - [read more](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html).

For instance if you want to **always show first item** and **show second item if there is room for it**:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/item_id1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon1"
        app:iconTint="@color/white"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="First item"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/item_id2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon2"
        app:iconTint="@color/white"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Second item"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: The question is about showing icons in the overflow menu. This does not awnser that at all