# @RestrictTo(LIBRARY_GROUP) preventing generation of signed APK

Tags: android

I'm attempting to generate a signed APK and receiving the following error:

```
Error:(59, 44) AppCompatButton.setSupportBackgroundTintList can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support)
```

Since the last time I've done so, `AppCompatButton.setSupportBackgroundTintList` has been annotated with `@RestrictTo(LIBRARY_GROUP)`.

When trying to generate the APK, lint flags this as an error. I've read [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150995/appcompatactivity-oncreate-can-only-be-called-from-within-the-same-library-group), however, suppressing the lint analysis still does not allow me to generate an APK, generating the same error as above.

So, I changed the call to conform with the new preferred way of making compat calls: `ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(view, tintList)`. Unfortunately, this change still does not allow me to generate a signed APK, generating the same error as above.

Android Studio version `3.1`
Build tools version `27.0.3`
Gradle wrapper version `gradle-4.5.1-all`
Android gradle build tools version `3.1.0`

What am I missing?

**Edit**

Well, this is weird and pretty embarrassing. Apparently, when I updated Android Studio and imported my settings, it allowed itself to continue displaying a now deprecated Messages window. This window wasn't receiving  messages being generated by the build output. After investigating further, I found that Messages output is now in the new Build window. After checking that output, it seems my problem was something else entirely.

The solution for @RestrictTo(LIBRARY_GROUP) continues to be using the appropriate compat call.

Comment: Do you mean [`setBackgroundTintList()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#setBackgroundTintList(android.view.View,%20android.content.res.ColorStateList)), instead of `setSupportBackgroundTintList()`?

Comment: No, I need to support API prior to 21 when `setBackgroundTintList()` was added. **edit**: scratch that, I see what you meant. The code is correct, I just mistyped

Comment: OK, just checking. So, you're getting this error now for that `ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList()` call? Or are you getting that error for some new problem? Also, what version of the Support Libraries are you using?

Comment: Actually, bizarrely, it's giving me the error on the line before the one containing `ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList()`. That line contains `view.setEnabled(false)`

Comment: That feels like the build system is looking at some code that is different than what you're editing.

Comment: I thought the same thing, so I've done a clean, invalidate cache and restart, and I've double-checked the directories. I can't find anything pointing to an out-of-date file.

Comment: The error message still refers to `AppCompatButton.setSupportBackgroundTintList()`? Are you referencing that anywhere else?

Comment: It does, and I am not. The error points specifically to the file I've fixed, and the line just before the line where the error used to point to. I can attach some screenshots if that helps.

Comment: I don't think screenshots will help me personally, though it might help others encountering your question. Frankly, right now, I'm stumped. Sorry!

Comment: Well, I appreciate you checking my sanity, even though we couldn't solve it. :)

Comment: @CommonsWare so, this ended up being an embarrassing issue. But I thought you'd be interested in knowing what happened (I put it in my edit).

Comment: Glad that you got to the bottom of it!