# How to hide actionbar in some fragments with Android Navigation Components?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I am using android navigation components to navigate fragments.
I can easily set action bar by using this code in the Main Activity :

```
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
```

But If I want to hide the supportActionbar in some of the fragments then what should be the best approach?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For the fragments that you want to hide the `SupportActionBar`, you can hide it in `onResume()` with `.hide()`, and show it again in `onStop()` with `.show()`

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ActionBar supportActionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) requireActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    if (supportActionBar != null)
        supportActionBar.hide();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    ActionBar supportActionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) requireActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    if (supportActionBar != null)
        supportActionBar.show();
}
```

Comment: It is working, but when you come to that fragment where you want to hide the actionbar it is showing actionbar for a while and hide it with default animation

Comment: @tahanaqvi welcome.. for the animation issue; you can disable it with `supportActionBar.setShowHideAnimationEnabled(false);`

Comment: There is another problem, when you hide the actionbar, minimize the application and come back.. empty white space at the bottom of the screen having height of action bar is shown

Comment: @tahanaqvi can you illustrate more especially with a picture .. I can't reproduce this issue in my testing app

Comment: I am unable to produce it again... I'll come to you again If I will get that issue :p
Anyways, thanks

Comment: Yes, but there is a red underline on it which is saying "ActionBar:setShowHideAnimationEnabled can only be called within the same library prefix"

Comment: @tahanaqvi this is a bug, you can solve it using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150995/appcompatactivity-oncreate-can-only-be-called-from-within-the-same-library-group#answer-41251316)

Comment: Be careful with this, there are certain situations where onStart of the next Fragment can be called before onStop of the previous fragment, thus leaving you with an ActionBar when you don't want one

Comment: setShowHideAnimationEnabled doesn't seem to fix the action bar pop in for me

Comment: Hi @Chucky it's a bit old; pls try to do the same in `navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener` by checking fragment Id; hopefully helps