# Not able to change radio button circle color in android

Tags: android, colors, radio-button

I am using `radioButton` in my app but by default my `radioButton` color is black and when I select it that turns to color accent color that I have mentioned in my `color.xml` but I want to change `radioButton` initial color and  selected color to white color. How I am able to do so. I tried background color but it changes background color property. Please help.

Comment: by default  selected color gets from style and that is colorAscent.. try new style and add it to your radio button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change color of a radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696275/change-color-of-a-radio-button)

Comment: @VishalThakkar  that is not providing any answer

Comment: have you try that answers solution?

Comment: `is not providing any answer` it **is providing** 9 answers, can't you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Put this code in style.xml

```
<!-- custom style -->
<style name="radionbutton"
       parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/rb_drawable</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

Now make rb_drawable.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_unchecked" android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_unchecked" android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="false"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_checked" android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_checked" android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="false"/>
</selector>
```

Now make 2 more files for radio button check/uncheck in drawable folder

**radio_unchecked.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="oval">
  <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
  <size android:width="30dp" android:height="30dp"/>
</shape>
```

**radio_checked.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
      <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
      <size android:width="30dp" android:height="30dp"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:top="5dp" android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
      <solid android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
      <size android:width="10dp" android:height="10dp"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Finally change style of radio button in layout xml

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    style="@style/radionbutton"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```