# How to change color of Radio buttons [the circle part] programmatically (java)?

Tags: android

I could only find these functions but none of them helped:

`setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);`,
`setTextColor(Color);`,
`setHighlightColor(Color);`

Comment: Radio button color comes from App theme. Either you may use custom theme or override the existing theme.

Comment: Use tint. Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29551017/4848308

Comment: But, button tint doesn't work < API 21 @GueorguiObregon

Comment: The App I'm making will have a lot of users on low end phones, hence cannot just make for API > 21

Comment: This will work for all devices http://stackoverflow.com/a/34519463/4848308 but certainly is no so straightforward like using tints

Answer (score 0):

**you can use**

```
  RadiobuttonObject.setButtonTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(parseColor("#FF08A8F9")));
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation about **why** one can "use" that? In which sense does it solve the original question?